# SQL Relational Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT dbo.Customers.Name, dbo.Items.Name AS ItemName,SUM(dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail.DeliveredQuantity) AS DeliveredQuantity
FROM   dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail 
INNER JOIN dbo.Customers ON dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail.BusinessUnitId = dbo.Customers.BusinessUnitId 
INNER JOIN dbo.Items ON dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail.BusinessUnitId = dbo.Items.BusinessUnitId AND dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail.ItemId = dbo.Items.ItemId
GROUP BY dbo.Customers.Name, dbo.Items.Name, dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail.DeliveredQuantity
```

I am writing this query to get sum of DeliveredQuantity my query is executing but he is not return sum of DeliveredQuantity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail.DeliveredQuantity should not be in group by clause, because you are summing this variable.

So try:

```
SELECT   dbo.Customers.Name, dbo.Items.Name AS ItemName,      SUM(dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail.DeliveredQuantity) AS DeliveredQuantity
 FROM          dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail INNER JOIN
dbo.Customers ON dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail.BusinessUnitId =dbo.Customers.BusinessUnitId INNER JOIN
dbo.Items ON dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail.BusinessUnitId = dbo.Items.BusinessUnitId AND dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail.ItemId = dbo.Items.ItemId
GROUP BY dbo.Customers.Name, dbo.Items.Name
```

Comment: SELECT   dbo.Customers.Name, dbo.Items.Name AS ItemName, dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail.CreatedOn,     SUM(dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail.DeliveredQuantity) AS DeliveredQuantity
FROM          dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail INNER JOIN
dbo.Customers ON dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail.BusinessUnitId = dbo.Customers.BusinessUnitId INNER JOIN
dbo.Items ON dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail.BusinessUnitId = dbo.Items.BusinessUnitId AND dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail.ItemId = dbo.Items.ItemId
GROUP BY dbo.Customers.Name, dbo.Items.Name, dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail.CreatedOn

Comment: i want to get all the records with same date.. when i put the date in my query he is return sum of deliveredQuantity

Comment: @Ali Please don't post new questions in comments. Ask a new question if you need something else.

Comment: When opening a new Question you should also clarify your question, i dont understand the problem, so you add date to group by and select,  What happens and what do you want to happen instead?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `DeliveredQuantity` from the `GROUP BY`, as it is an aggregated column:

```
SELECT c.Name, 
       i.Name                   AS ItemName, 
       SUM(d.DeliveredQuantity) AS DeliveredQuantity 
FROM   dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail d
       INNER JOIN dbo.Customers c
               ON d.BusinessUnitId = c.BusinessUnitId 
       INNER JOIN dbo.Items i
               ON d.BusinessUnitId = i.BusinessUnitId 
                  AND d.ItemId = i.ItemId 
GROUP  BY c.Name, 
          i.Name
```